# How to style Gravity Forms field, enable enhanced user interface?

Tags: css, gravityforms

I wanted to apply "Enhanced user interface" to a field that helps users search through a list of schools. My CSS is not applying correctly to the dropdown in this field.

I'm using Avada theme. I added CSS to theme in Customizing Additional CSS. All classes apply to all Gravity Form fields except the enhanced one.

```
body .gform_wrapper .gform_body {
    font-size: 20px !important;
        letter-spacing: 1.5px !important;
        line-height: 25px !important;
        margin-bottom: 80px !important;
}

body .gform_wrapper .gform_body .gfield_label {
    font-size: 18px !important;
        font-weight: 400 !important;
        letter-spacing: 1.5px !important;
        line-height: 25px !important;
        margin-top: 10px !important;
}

body .gform_wrapper .gform_body .gform_fields .gfield input[type=text]
{
  border: 1px solid #ccc !important;  
    font-size: 20px !important;
    font-weight: 500 !important;
    color: #676767 !important;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px !important;
    line-height: 25px !important;
    border-radius: 0px !important;

}

body .gform_wrapper .gform_body .gform_fields .gfield .gfield_checkbox
{
  border: 0px !important;  
    font-size: 20px !important;
    font-weight: 400 !important;
    color: #676767 !important;
    letter-spacing: 1.5px !important;
    line-height: 25px !important;
    border-radius: 0px !important;

}

body .gform_wrapper .gform_body .gform_fields .gfield select
{
  border: 1px solid #ccc !important;  
    font-size: 20px !important;
    font-weight: 400 !important;
    color: #676767 !important;
    padding: 10px !important;
    border-radius: 0px !important;

}

.wpf-autocomplete {
    border: 1px solid #ccc !important;  
    font-size: 20px !important;
    font-weight: 400 !important;
    color: #676767 !important;
    padding: 10px !important;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
}
```

I tried creating a custom CSS class for this field and adding it to Appearance>Custom CSS of the schools field. That didn't work.

```
.wpf-autocomplete {
    border: 1px solid #ccc !important;  
    font-size: 20px !important;
    font-weight: 400 !important;
    color: #676767 !important;
    padding: 10px !important;
    border-radius: 0px !important;
}
```

The dropdown takes on a deafult size. The search field when I click on the dropdown is the correct size, so that field is picking up the CSS.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/86saq.png)

Any suggestions?

Comment: Include the relevant CSS or HTML and we can try to help

Comment: I updated original post with code and screenshot of form.